# How I receive a number on Textfield Input in FLET?

Tags: python, user-input, textfield, flet

im learning Flet to build apps with python, how do i receive a user parameter on TextField but has a Number (int or float), because is STR by standart. here´s the code

`quantity = TextField("How many company´s you want to add? ")

```
list = list()
company = dict()
user = dict()
list_companies = list()

# Informs the values ​​of each company
def btn_empresas(e):
    for position in range(1, quantity + 1):
        company ["value"] = TextField(f"What is the VALUE of the company's RESERVOIR {position}: ")
        company ["index"] = TextField(f"Enter the INDEX of the company {position}: ")
        company ["volume"] = TextField(f"What is the VOLUME of the company {position}: ")
        list.append(company.copy())
        Text(f"You added the company {position}")`
```

Hey there, im learning Flet to build apps with python, how do i receive a user parameter on TextField but has a Number (int or float), because is STR by standart. here´s the code

`quantity = TextField("How many company´s you want to add? ")

```
list = list()
company = dict()
user = dict()
list_companies = list()

# Informs the values ​​of each company
def btn_empresas(e):
    for position in range(1, quantity + 1):
        company ["value"] = TextField(f"What is the VALUE of the company's RESERVOIR {position}: ")
        company ["index"] = TextField(f"Enter the INDEX of the company {position}: ")
        company ["volume"] = TextField(f"What is the VOLUME of the company {position}: ")
        list.append(company.copy())
        Text(f"You added the company {position}")`
```

I saw on Docs about KeyboardType but I didn't understand[set keyboartype to NUMBER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK9bT.png)

The goal is use the user number input to set how many company's will me add on the program.

Answer (score 1):

to put a type of keyboard according to documentation, you have to put a enum from class flet.KeyBoardType, ie

```
company ["value"] = TextField(f"What is the VALUE of the company's RESERVOIR {position}: ", keyboard_type= KeyboardType.NUMBER)
```

If you want to catch data from that TextField, you have to use the param 'data', and use a function

```
company ["value"] = TextField(value=<value you want to catch>, keyboard_type= KeyboardType.NUMBER)
```

And
def
(self, e):
data = e.control.value

Comment: Hey man, thanks for you reply, i'l try that @fsalazar_sch